# sql query not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This query (command in method CalculateCGPA) works perfectly well in mysql Workbench. It returns only 1 row and 1 column that contains a cgpa of 2.00. i wanted to store it in my cgpa string but it gives an error on this line:
cgpa = Convert.ToString(myReader.GetString(0));

error says that:
"Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

PLEASE NOTE THAT BEFORE COMING TO ERROR LINE ABOVE PROGRAM HAS ALREADY PASSED THE IF STATEMENT TEST SHOWING THAT READER IS NOT NULL.

Can anybody assist me regarding it?

```
public string GetStudentID()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            conn.Open();
            string STDid = "SELECT Student_ID from Student";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(STDid, conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(Convert.ToString(myReader.GetString(0)));

            }
            myReader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            string[] array = list.ToArray();


                string newcgpa = CalculateCGPA(array[0]);
                return newcgpa;



        }


        public string CalculateCGPA(string arrayElement)
        {
            string cgpa;
            conn.Open();
            string command = "SELECT ROUND((sum(enroll.Enroll_Grade_Point*course.Crs_Credits) /sum(course.Crs_Credits)),2) as CGPA FROM student, enroll, course, class Where student.Student_ID = enroll.Student_ID AND enroll.Class_Code = class.Class_Code and class.Crs_Code = course.Crs_Code and student.Student_ID = '" + arrayElement + "'";

 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (myReader.Read())
            {
                cgpa = Convert.ToString(myReader.GetString(0));
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                myReader.Close();

                return cgpa;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                myReader.Close();
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

myReader.GetString should not be called on DBNull values

```
 list.Add(Convert.ToString(myReader.GetString(0)));
```

**try this instead**

```
myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetString(0)) ? null : reader.GetString(0)
```

Comment: Shall i write it like this:   cgpa=myReader.IsDbNull(myReader.GetString(0)) ? null : reader.GetString(0)

Comment: Error 1 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsDbNull' and no extension method 'IsDbNull' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\web\Login\Login\Connection.cs 151 33 Login

Comment: use IsDBNull() instead IsDbNull(). Sry i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You say that this query returns just one line and one column. 
So, in this case, it is better to call ExecuteScalar instead of building a reader, initialize it and extract....

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
 object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if(result != null)
 {
    cpga = Convert.ToString(result);
 }
```

Also do not use string concatenation to build sql strings, but use parametrized query because you are exposed to Sql Injection Attacks

```
string command = "SELECT ROUND((sum(enroll.Enroll_Grade_Point*course.Crs_Credits) " + 
                 "/sum(course.Crs_Credits)),2) as CGPA FROM student, enroll, course, " + 
                 "class Where student.Student_ID = enroll.Student_ID AND " + 
                 "enroll.Class_Code = class.Class_Code and " + 
                 "class.Crs_Code = course.Crs_Code and " + 
                 "student.Student_ID = @element";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@element", arrayElement);
```

And the Student_ID field is really a string field? If it is numeric then convert the arrayElement to the proper numeric type (`Convert.ToInt32(arrayElement)`)

However, if you still want to use a MySqlDataReader to get back the value, then add a bit of sanity checks.

For example the [SqlDataReader documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) suggest to call [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) before trying to call GetString().

The same documentation says that you could get an InvalidCastException if you try to read a value that is not a string, so instead of calling GetString(0) and then Convert.ToString(string) return directly the data object with reader[0] and let the conversion happen in the Convert.ToString().

I am pretty sure that these suggestion are still valid for the MySqlDataReader.....

So I will change the reading line in this way

```
cgpa = (myReader.IsDBNull(0) ? "0" : Convert.ToString(myReader[0]));
```

Note that also if the myReader.Read returns true, this doesn't mean that the CPGA is not null because the join between tables could break and the where condition could exclude every record.
A possible change in the query could be to use explicit joins, but this doesn't allow to avoid the null check.

```
string command = "SELECT ROUND((sum(e.Enroll_Grade_Point*c.Crs_Credits) " + 
                 "/sum(c.Crs_Credits)),2) as CGPA " + 
                 "FROM student s INNER JOIN enroll e ON s.Student_ID = e.Student_ID " + 
                 "INNER JOIN class c ON e.Class_Code = c.Class_Code " + 
                 "INNER JOIN course u ON c.Crs_Code = u.Crs_Code "
                 "WHERE s.Student_ID = @element";
```

Comment: How is that an answer to OP's question?

Comment: The query might only return one record now because it's in development.  Later on, it might return more.

Comment: Then use the SqlDataReader, but do not try to use GetString on a Numeric result like that. I will also try to add explicit joins between tables and test it with MySqlWorkbench

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using string concatenation -- the problem is with using data that was entered by users.